# Show folder structure in Sphinx+Doxygen documentation

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

I am trying to migrate my C++ code documentation to [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) (and using [Breathe](https://breathe.readthedocs.io) as a bridge).

In [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl) I like having a [file list page](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout) where the folder structure of the project is shown. The files shown there are clickable and lead you to a page with the actual code.

Is it possible to do something similar in Sphinx?

I know is possible to show the actual code by using the `literalinclude` directive. So I need a folder structure that redirects to a `literalinclude` for each file. In principle this can be done by hand, but I want to know if there is an automatic way of doing this.

Comment: Do you want something like this https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html where the [source](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/_modules/pyramid/authentication.html#AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy) is linked? That extension is called [`sphinx.ext.viewcode`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html).

Comment: That is an interesting extension thank you. Unfortunately looks like it won't work with doxygen classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it is not possible to have C++ file hierarchies self-generated by Sphinx+Breathe. Fortunately there is an additional extension called [exhale](https://exhale.readthedocs.io/) which can do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

If so, you need [Exhale](https://exhale.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Exhale creates a hierarchy of rst files shadowing the Doxygen-created-hierarchy.

I followed the steps in [Quickstart Guide](https://exhale.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#quickstart-guide), even have a different source and build tree, and everything worked just fine, including source code listing. Exhale documentation is really good.

I am not able to see the contents of Doxygen `\mainpage`, but that's another story.